# How to keep only max value of row and convert other value to NA?

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(
  cola = c(3,NA,NA,NA,1,5),
  colb = c(7,NA,NA,NA,NA,6),
  colc = c(NA, NA, 10, NA, NA, 6)
)
```

Use above data.frame as example,I want to keep the max value of each row, and convert other value to NA,which means convert origin data.frame

```
cola colb colc
   3    7   NA
  NA   NA   NA
  NA   NA   10
  NA   NA   NA
   1   NA   NA
   5    6   6
```

to expect result as below:

```
cola colb colc
NA    7   NA
NA   NA   NA
NA   NA   10
NA   NA   NA
1   NA   NA
NA    6   6
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` to loop over the rows (`MARGIN = 1`) and `replace` the values that are not equal to `max` with `NA`, assign the transpose back to the original object

```
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) replace(x, x != max(x, na.rm = TRUE), NA)))
```

---

Or with `rowMaxs`

```
library(matrixStats)
i1 <- !!rowSums(!is.na(df))
df[i1,] <-  replace(df[i1,], df[i1,] != rowMaxs(as.matrix(df[i1,]), 
                na.rm = TRUE)[col(df[i1,])], NA)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate(new = reduce(., pmax, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  transmute_at(vars(starts_with('col')), ~ replace(., .!= new, NA))
```

Comment: It works,any other method can be used in pipe?Thanks.

Comment: How about `t(apply(df, 1, function(x) replace(x, x != max(x, na.rm = TRUE), NA))) %>% data.frame`?

Comment: @kittygirl that also works, but it is better to do `[] <-` to keep the structure of the original columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purrr::pmap_df`

```
purrr::pmap_df(df, ~{
      vec <- c(...)
      ifelse(vec != max(vec, na.rm = TRUE), NA, vec)
})

# A tibble: 6 x 3
#   cola  colb  colc
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    NA     7    NA
#2    NA    NA    NA
#3    NA    NA    10
#4    NA    NA    NA
#5     1    NA    NA
#6    NA     6     6
```